# Speeding up identification of subsequences

Tags: r, traminer

I am using a dataset which has hundreds of events in each sequence. I am trying to identify subsequences and sequential association rules using `TraMineR`. For example, here is code that I would write:

```
# Frequent subsequences:
fsubseq <- seqefsub(weaver, minSupport = 0.05, maxK = 4)
fsubseq <- seqentrans(fsubseq)
fsb <- fsubseq[fsubseq$data$nevent > 1]
plot(fsb[1:20], col = "cyan")

# Sequential association rules:
rules <- TraMineR:::seqerules(fsubseq)
rules[order(rules$Lift, decreasing = TRUE)[1:25], 1:4]
```

This is usually workable as long as I set maxK to 1-3, but as I move over that value the computations takes hours if not days. Are there any specific parameters I can adjust to speed these computations up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computation time is strongly linked to:

- Number of events per sequence. The algorithm was designed for a small number of event per sequence (<6 typically) and many sequences. You can try removing some events that are not your main interest or analysing group of events. I guess that the relationship between number of events and computation time is at least exponential. With more than 10 events per sequences, it can be really slow.
- Minimum support. With low minimum support the possible number of subsequence get really big. Try to set it to an higher value.

Hope this helps.